# Effective Parallel Backends for RStudio Server Environment

Tags: r, foreach, multicore, rstudio-server, domc

I am working in a large server environement.  For example, when I run detectCores() from the parallel library, I get a print out of 48.  I would like to use this environment efficiently.  What parallel backend should one use in this environment?

I have searched around, and it seems as though certain packages are best for server environments, while others work best within gui environments.  But what about a blended environment such as RStudio Server?

Comment: If you came to a stable solution I'd be curious to find out about it.

Comment: I have found that using ```parallel``` functions such ass ```mclapply```, ```pvec```, and ```foreach``` on RStudio Server seems to work fine (despite the warning given by the ```doMC``` package).  The runtimes seem to be very similar to running ```R``` straight from the terminal.

Comment: @Mike.Gahan In your benchmarks, were you sourcing your scripts or executing them line by line? I wonder if that would make a difference in whether `parallel` forks GUI elements . . .